# Can I avoid "_rev" from my couchDB entry because My document is not going to change

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I am working on couchdb with nodejs where I have requirement where my document is added once and only once. I think there is no need of _rev tag in my Document. As _rev value is long string and my data is very small it adds a big overhead and finally big document size. I am aware it is very integral part of couchdb but in some typical cases it becomes redundant.
NOTE I also know that couchDB uses Multi-Version Concurrency Control (MVCC).

1. Is there a way to remove this from Document ?
2. Am I missing out something of critical which may create issue later ?
3. If not avoid it completely atleast can I reduce the value very small ?

My point here is in short :

can I have entry like

"_id": "001" "value":"12"

"_id": "002" "value":"23"

where there is no such value as "_rev": "1-8b0b70974c6dd43edf4e07f12a9655af"

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the `_rev` property transmitted when downloading a document, you can always use a [show function](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html#show-functions) to transform your document's JSON to exclude this property:

```
function (doc, req) {
  delete(doc._rev)
  return { json: doc }
}
```

This does mean you have to use the [show function API](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/ddoc/render.html#db-design-design-doc-show-show-name-doc-id) instead of fetching the document directly, but you can use this approach to apply other domain-specific optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But the thing I am concern about is server disk space. as there are millions of docs are expected so cumulative size is far too more. But this answer is one step closer to my solution. Thanks Again.

Comment: What does disk space have to do with a show function? It is run on your document as it is being sent to the client, not stored on disk like a view.

Comment: Hi Dominic, I think I misstated in my above comment. So my concern here was disk space used by Database document because of two fields _id, and _rev I need to find a way to tackle this issue. I have 10 chars(bytes) of payload with 32 chars of _id and 32 chars of _rev which is lot compared to my data. So I was not concern of transmitting my data to external server but I am trying to save my disk space due to this overhead of _rev at-least for now.

Comment: If you aren't using revisions AND you're very concerned the size of each individual entry, it's possible that couchdb isn't the right solution to your current problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to disable revisions in CouchDB. Revisions are the integral part of the database. If you are sure that you don't want them then you may want to use some other database but if you use Mongo then it will store revisions. But look at it this way: if you have a requirement that your documents never change then how are you going to guarantee that? A revisions seems like a perfect feature to make sure that your documents never change. Not only because you can read them but also because if you never use them then you will not be able do update any document for which a previous revision is needed for updates.

Comment: yes sir,  but there is no chance it can be modified by something. and if it is integral part then ,can you help me out at-least reduce size of it ?